# Why GCP IAM user are auto-added to sudoers file while ssh connect?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, identity-management

I have rights issue with my Ubuntu 22.04 VM instance.

### The Problem

The users are auto-added to the sudoers file during the first SSH connection so any users have acces to root privileges.

specificaly the following file is generated: `/var/google-sudoers.d/<IAM_USERS_OR_SA_NAME>_orange_com`

```
<IAM_USERS_OR_SA_NAME>_orange_com ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

And is included by this file: `/etc/sudoers.d/google-oslogin`

```
#includedir /var/google-sudoers.d
```

What can I do to avoid this auto-add ?

### Context

- The users are **created** during the **first SSH connection** (doesn't exist before on the VM).
- The users are authenticated through the **IAP**
- The users have the default role `Editor`

Comment: In the design of compute engine, each account has access to everything. By default, the root user is not enabled (no password). That means sudo must be enabled. Once the VM is booted, you can configure it as you desire. You can save that configuration as an image and launch new instances from that configured image.